# Use variable as key in JSON data object to get value

Tags: json, key, var

I have a given JSON object .

```
var item = {VENUE_ID: "146", Cost: 0, Impressions: 0, Position: 0, id: 6} ;
```

I can extract value by item.VENUE_ID  ,item.Cost.

How can i use variable to extract value .I want something like it

```
var keys="VENUE_ID";

item.keys or item[keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it we can use following code to set key dynamic and get value  item["" + keys+ ""]

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
item[keys]
```

works perfectly where `keys = "VENUE_ID"`

Anyone facing this requirement, try and access the value the aforesaid way, even the OP posted the correct method in his question. I'm not sure why it didn't work for him in the first place.